# Does Enter key trigger a click event?

Tags: angular, dom-events

In the code below `removeSelectedCountry()` should be called when a `span` element is clicked and `handleKeyDown($event)` should be called when there is a `keydown` event on a `div`.

```
@Component({
    selector: "wng-country-picker",
    template: `
    <ul class="CountryPicker-selected" *ngIf="selectedCountries.length > 0">
    <li *ngFor="let country of selectedCountries">
        <span class="Pill Pill--primary" (click)="removeSelectedCountry(country)">
        {{ country.name }}
        </span>
    </li>
    </ul> 
    <div (keydown)="handleKeyDown($event)" class="CountryPicker-input"></div>
`,
providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
```

But `removeSelectedCountry()` is called every time <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

To make the code work, I had to change the `click` event to `mousedown` event.
It works fine now.

Can anyone explain why the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key would trigger the `click` event?

```
@Component({
    selector: "wng-country-picker",
    template: `
    <ul class="CountryPicker-selected" *ngIf="selectedCountries.length > 0">
    <li *ngFor="let country of selectedCountries">
        <span class="Pill Pill--primary" (mousedown)="removeSelectedCountry(country)">
        {{ country.name }}
        </span>
    </li>
    </ul> 
    <div (keydown)="handleKeyDown($event)" class="CountryPicker-input"></div>
`,
providers: [CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
```

Adding class snipppet:

```
export class CountryPickerComponent {

private selectedCountries: CountrySummary[] = new Array();

private removeSelectedCountry(country: CountrySummary){
    // check if the country exists and remove from selectedCountries
    if (this.selectedCountries.filter(ctry => ctry.code === country.code).length > 0)
    {
        var index = this.selectedCountries.indexOf(country);
        this.selectedCountries.splice(index, 1);
        this.selectedCountryCodes.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

private handleKeyDown(event: any)
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13)
    {
       // action
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 40)
    {
        // action
    }  
    else if (event.keyCode == 38)
    {
        // action
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 157):

For ENTER key, why not use `(keyup.enter)`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'key-up3',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup.enter)="values=box.value">
    <p>{{values}}</p>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v3 {
  values = '';
}
```

Comment: I need to perform action based on the key pressed, so `(keyup.enter)` would not help

Comment: You could add all 3 events like keyup.xxx

Answer (score 68):

Here is the correct **SOLUTION**!
Since the button doesn't have a defined attribute type, angular maybe attempting to issue the keyup event as a submit request and triggers the click event on the button.

```
<button type="button" ...></button>
```

Big thanks to DeborahK!

[Angular2 - Enter Key executes first (click) function present on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662314/angular2-enter-key-executes-first-click-function-present-on-the-form/43662397#43662397)

Comment: unfortunately, in the form above there is no button component. The click was triggered on a `<span>`

Comment: It’s a suggestion for a workaround as others are so inclined.

Comment: Accurate answer, I was missing the type attribute.

Answer (score 41):

Use `(keyup.enter)`.

Angular can filter the key events for us. Angular has a special syntax for keyboard events. We can listen for just the Enter key by binding to Angular's `keyup.enter` pseudo-event.

Answer (score 20):

For angular 6 there is a new way of doing it.
On your input tag add

```
(keyup.enter)="keyUpFunction($event)"
```

Where `keyUpFunction($event)` is your function.

Answer (score 15):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'key-up3',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup.enter)="doSomething($event)">
    <p>{{values}}</p>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v3 {
  doSomething(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 4):

```
<form (keydown)="someMethod($event)">
     <input type="text">
</form>
```

```
someMethod(event:any){
   if(event.keyCode == 13){
      alert('Entered Click Event!');
   }else{
   }
}
```

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated.. use `key` instead

Answer (score 1):

What personally me fount usable for me is:

```
(mousedown)="callEvent()" (keyup.enter)="$event.preventDefault()
```

`keyup.enter` prevents the event from triggering on keyup, but it still occurs for keydown, that works for me.