# Angular click event identify whether it is mouse click or keyboard enter key event

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following html code, I need to identify whether the event is mouse click event or keyboard enter key event.

Html code

```
    <button mat-raised-button class="btn-enter-troubleshooting-attempts" 
(click)="triggerLog($event)"> Click/Enter </button>
```

Type script

```
triggerLog(e): void {
    console.log('Log Attempt', e);
   //do some function based on the event
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `(keydown)="triggerLog($event)"` and then check if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed in `app.component.ts`:

```
triggerLog(e): void { 
  console.log('Log Attempt', e);

  if(e.code === 13) {
    // Enter pressed.
  }
}
```

If you want to listen to `keypress` or `keydown` with no selection:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.triggerLog, true);
}
```

You can check keyboard codes at https://keycode.info/.

Comment: if we write `(keypress)` then mouse click is not working, then how to handle that situation

Comment: add window event to ngOnInit

Comment: ```
ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.triggerLog, true)
  }
```

Comment: Note both `keypress` and `e.keyCode` are depreacted, so you should probably be using `e.key` or `e.code` instead. Also, this line is wrong: `e.code === 13`. You have 4 alternatives there: `e.key === 'Enter'`, `e.code === 'Ender'`, `e.which === 13` (deprecated) or `e.keyCode === 13` (deprecated).

Comment: Also, take a look at this other tool https://keyjs.dev, that has a bit more information about the different keyboard events and their properties. 

Answer (score 0):

Use (keyup.enter) to bind to enter key. Use (click) to listen to mouse clicks.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37939193/2148050)

Comment: (click) can able to handle mouse click and enter key event, but (keyup.enter) only able to perform when press enter key. So you r trying to say that `(click)="triggerLog($event)"  (keyup.enter) = "triggerLog($event)"` i need to use both together

Comment: Technically, after thinking about it, user should not be able to press enter key on a button element. if user is able to navigate to a button by pressing tab key, then you could always set tabIndex="-1" on a button to skip selection on this button.

Answer (score 0):

you only need ask about event.clientX, if has any value is a click, else is an ENTER

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="name">
    <button type="submit" (click)="triggerLog($event)">click</button>
</form>

  form=new FormGroup({
    name:new FormControl('')
  })
  triggerLog(event)
  {
    console.log(event.clientX)
  }
```

See [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcpkbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)